# WordPress on VirtualBox - no pretty permalinks

Tags: permalinks, redirect, apache

Right, this has me stumped.

I cannot get the pretty permalinks to work.  They go to 404.

The permalinks are updating, I can see the URL change to each setting as I save them by going to a post, but only the default "p=ID" works.

- Wordpress is installed under /var/www/html/
- .htaccess is being created and updated whenever I update the
  permalinks
- Owners and Permissions are set to www-data:www-pub and 755/644
  (dir/file)
- AllowOverride All is set in the [my-site].conf file
- mod_rewrite is enabled
- apache2 has been restarted (several times).

Any ideas which I've not tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... and as per usual, I figure it out as soon as I post the question -.-

[Using this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/992620/660221), I changed **apache2.conf** under */etc/apache2/*.

There is a section towards the bottom talking about the security model.  The section **Directory /var/www/** needs to be changed from *AllowOverride None* to *AllowOverride All*.

I restarted apache and it works.