# WordPress Permalinks still not working despite all necessary settings

Tags: permalinks, apache, mod-rewrite

I apologize for the seemingly duplicate issue posting but I can't seem to find someone who has come across my specific issue and resolved it. [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296764/wordpress-on-virtualbox-no-pretty-permalinks) got close but I did everything they did.

here's where I'm at:

- migrated a wp site to an AWS server running ubuntu 18
- rewrite mod is enabled
- site is in `/home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site`
- site dir is owned by www-data
- site's virtual hosts file has the necessary `"Directory"` section with `"AllowOverride All"` set
- site's .htaccess file has the rewrite rules set by the permalinks settings in the UI
- apache2 config also has the `"AllowOverride All"` set for a `"Directory"` section pointed at `/home/ubuntu/sites`

What am I missing?

### .htaccess

*contents after setting the permalinks to date and time (empty otherwise)*

```
 BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>
Options -Indexes

                                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                                        RewriteEngine On
                                        RewriteBase /
                                        RewriteRule ^/wp-content/endurance-page-cache/ - [L]
                                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
                                        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
                                        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(wordpress_test_cookie|comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_logg$
                                        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/endurance-page-cache/$1/_index.html -f
                                        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/endurance-page-cache/$1/_index.html [L]
                                </IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### apache2.conf

```
...
<Directory /home/ubuntu/sites/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

### vhost for site

```
...
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com
...
<Directory /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Comment: What is the `DocumentRoot`? When you say the vHost has the necessary `Directory` section, can you confirm the file system path this is set for. Please include the contents of your .htaccess file and where exactly this is located. If you add some *nonsense* to your .htaccess file, does it “break”?

Comment: The site is working fine so the vhost settings are accurate. The directory is pointed at the site (/home/ubunut/sites/mywpsite).  I've updated the question with the .htaccess.

Comment: "The site is working fine so the vhost settings are accurate." - but how can you be sure; permalinks aren't working? There is a syntax error on one of your _CondPattern_s here: `|wordpress_logg$` - which implies either mod_rewrite is not enabled or `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled (otherwise you'd be getting a 500 response).

Comment: @MrWhite - If the directory root is inaccurately entered in the vhost, then even the front page wouldn't render. Correct? mod_rewrite is enabled and confirmed by the console when I try to enable it. The typo in the .htaccess is a mystery considering I didn't put any of that in there manually. It was generated by selecting the radio button in the Permalinks settings.

Comment: "If the directory root is inaccurately entered in the vhost, then even the front page wouldn't render. Correct?" - Not necessarily, there's insufficient info in the question. If your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/home/ubuntu/sites`, but are accessing your site as `example.com/my-wp-site/` then the "front page" would render correctly but permalinks would not. However, the "syntax error" I mentioned above is a show-stopper and suggests your vHost/server config is indeed misconfigured (as stated).

Comment: Okay, thank you. Are you suggesting that if the vhost is configured that would cause a typo in the automatically generated .htaccess file contents by WordPress? -- please notice the updates to my question as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113254/discussion-between-fischgeek-and-mrwhite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the domain/site has an ssl, the vhosts file for the ssl is separate and also needs to be updated. Not just the normal port 80 entry.

### vhost (:80)

*my-wp-site.com.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com
...
<Directory /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

### vhost (:443)

*my-wp-site.com-le-ssl.conf*

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ServerName my-wp-site.com
    ServerAlias my-wp-site.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/sites/my-wp-site.com>
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```